# Насколько устойчив порядок вычисления логических выражений? Может ли он быть оптимизирован на этапе компиляции?

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток.

В качестве сниппетов для небольших транзакций (в целях сохранения целостности данных) у меня давно прописалась такая конструкция:

```
public deleteSomething() {
    return 
        self::_tr_start() 
        && parent::delete() // удаляем "объект-себя"
        && $this->deleteSomethingRelated() // удаляем связанные данные (связанные записи в БД, связанные файлы, что угодно)
        && self::_tr_commit() 
        || self::_tr_rollback();
}

protected static function _tr_start() {
    return Db::getInstance()->query('START TRANSACTION;');
}
protected static function _tr_commit() {
    return Db::getInstance()->query('COMMIT;');
}
protected static function _tr_rollback() {
    Db::getInstance()->query('ROLLBACK;');
    return false; // chain should return false on fail
}
```

Если все "удаляторы" в цепочке возвращают булевые (или приводимые к ним) ответы да/нет в случае удачи/ошибки, то я ожидаю, что в случае успеха, будут по очереди вызваны все методы вплоть до коммита (а роллбэк вызван не будет, ибо true||something == true), а в случае ошибки на любом из шагов, вычисление ветки, объединенной AND-ами, прервется, и сразу будет вызван роллбэк.

Так вот, НА ПРАКТИКЕ, все работает именно так, но меня все время гложит мысль: а не может ли PHP, при каких-нибудь обстоятельствах, как-то заоптимизировать код, и нарушить порядок выполнения?

Ну например, может ли он обнаружить, что _tr_rollback всегда возвращает FALSE, и вообеще не вызывать его, т.к. вызывай/не вызывай, это НЕ влияет на итоговое значение логического выражения?

Или, скажем, если я сделаю вот так (ну, понадобилось, для отладки):

```
return
    self::_tr_start() 
    && parent::delete() 
    && $this->deleteSomethingRelated() 
    && false // CONSTANT FALSE
    && self::_tr_commit() 
    || self::_tr_rollback();
```

может ли компилятор меня перехитрить, и ВООБЩЕ не дергать первую ветку, и сразу вызвать роллбэк?

Повторюсь, на практике я с таким поведением еще ни разу не сталкивался, но, как говорится, если я этого не видел - это не значит, что такого не может быть :)

Заранее спасибо за инфу.

Comment: Разве php компилируется? Он интерпритируется

Comment: формально язык то интерпретируемый, а не компилируемый, так что вряд ли он что-то может выкинуть. А вот по поводу полного вычисления логического выражения, возможно есть настройки, которые влияют на то, будет ли выполняться ваш `rollback`  или нет, если первая часть вернет `true`, а как это бывает в других языках.

Comment: ну не совсем так... просто он перекомпилируется каждый раз на лету (а в случае opcache - может и не перекомпилироваться)... но вопрос-то не в этом, "чистый" интерпретатор, в теории, тоже может хитрить и оптимизировать

Answer (score 1):

Да, порядок будет соблюден, так как php поддерживает это https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation Но только нужно быть осторожным. `||` и `&&` поддерживают сокращенное вычисление (оно же ленивое), а вот `|` и `&` уже вычисляются полностью.

На странице [Logical Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) есть упоминания о short-circuit:

> // foo() will never get called as those operators are short-circuit

так что если код и сломается, то это будет вина пхп разработчиков.

Comment: ну да, ленивое (или как его там) вычисление - это какраз то, на чем идея и основана... но вопрос в том, может ли PHP как-то еще укоротить эту логику?

Comment: думаю, что если и может, то без побочных эффектов.

Comment: вот я тоже так думаю... но `думаю !== уверен`, это и не дает порой спать спокойно :)

Comment: если хочется спать спокойно - переходите на с++ - там это гарантируется на уровне стандарта (5.15-5.16)

Comment: c PHP на CPP? отличный совет :)))

Comment: обновил ответ. на официальной странице есть нужное упоминание.

Comment: там говорится только о том, что ИЗБЫТОЧНЫХ вычислений не будет... но не говорится о том, что часть вызовов не может быть опущена (как в моем примере, в случае `foo() && bar() && false`)

Comment: я не знаю, есть ли у пхп что то типа "официального стандарта" кроме как офсайта. Но учитывая, что php вырос с перла, а там подобные конструкции - норма, то все ок.

Но если  страшно - не используйте пхп и вообще не программируйте:)

Comment: трус не играет в PHP? :)))